# NSTimer don't call the method in selector

Tags: ios, swift

Hello

I'm trying to execute a task in background because I need to while the application is running being pulling data from the server. I write the code in the AppDelegate.swift, this is the code that i wrote:

```
    class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, UISplitViewControllerDelegate {

        var window: UIWindow?
        let manager = AppManager.manager
        var timer: NSTimer? = nil

        func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
            // Override point for customization after application launch.
            self.timer = NSTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: "UpdateDeviceData:", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
           return true
         }                                                                                                           
         func UpdateDeviceData(timer:NSTimer) {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), { () -> Void in
               print("do some background task")

               dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                  print("update some UI")

            })
        })
    }

}
```

I put a breakpoint in the line "print" and it never being executed.

Please any idea about what could be the problem?

**Note:**I'm using Xcode 7 beta and Swift

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to schedule the timer on a run loop - you're just assigning it to a variable. Try using the class method  `+ scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats:` -

so

```
NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.0, target: self, selector: "UpdateDeviceData:", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

Comment: thank you @RichTolley, do you have any example of using this method?

Comment: **WARNING:** @JoseRaulPerera It's important to note that using the class method will cause the `target` to be _retained_ by the timer. This means that the target _will not be dealloc'ed_ until the `NSTimer` instance resulting from this class method is _invalidated_ via the timer's `invalidate` method. Though it won't matter in this _specific_ context, it's a common mistake for those that are new to using scheduled `NSTimer` instances.

Comment: @RichTolley, I change my code to use your suggestion: `self.timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.4, target: self, selector: "UpdateDeviceData", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)`, and i got the following exception:

Comment: 2015-10-14 20:24:25.131 RapidSentryMaster[2116:356793] -[RapidSentryMaster.AppDelegate UpdateDeviceData]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f8879519270
2015-10-14 20:24:25.156 RapidSentryMaster *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[RapidSentryMaster.AppDelegate UpdateDeviceData]: unrecognized selector

Comment: UpdateDeviceData: If you miss the : it's a different method

Comment: @ThuggishNuggets, thank you you're right but this is what I need, to be continue until I stopped with `timer.invalidate()`

Comment: Clarified my comment was not for this specific context.

Comment: @RichTolley, thank you very much, you are the best, it is working with your example!!!!

Comment: @Thuggish Nuggests is definitely right that to say that you need to be careful with the class method though, otherwise you can inadvertently end up with multiple timers and memory issues. But as long as you remember to invalidate it you'll be ok